# Problema ao carregar dados com Entity Framework usando Include

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, expressões-lambda

Estou usando o **Entity Framework** com o **MySql** no meu sistema e preciso fazer uma consulta específica que inclua uma lista de um tipo de *Model* (`ApplicationUser`), nesta lista cada objeto retornado tem em suas propriedades um outro `Model`. Ou seja, Cada 'ApplicationUser' tem uma lista do tipo **'Veiculo'** ***(one-to-many)*** e cada veiculo tem o seu **ApplicationUser (Motorista)**, porém quando vou usar direto na *view*, noto que o motorista de cada veículo está sempre nulo, mesmo eu dando o `include` desta forma:

```
context.Veiculos.Include(veiculo => veiculo.Motorista).ToList();
```

Veiculo Model:

```
 [DisplayColumn("Nome")]
    [Table("Veiculos")]
    public class Veiculo
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid VeiculoID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid MotoristaID { get; set; }
        //[Required]
        //public Guid EnderecoID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Guid EmpresaID { get; set; }

        //[Display(Name = "Address", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        //public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Company", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Empresa { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Driver", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual ApplicationUser Motorista { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mark", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Marca { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Model", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Modelo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Year", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public int Ano { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "LicensePlate", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Placa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Color", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Cor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "RENAVANCode", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public long Renavan { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "NumberOfPassangers", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public int NumeroPassageiros { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "ExtraBaggage", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public double PesoExtra { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Trailer", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public bool Carretinha { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Excluded", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public bool Excluido { get; set; }
    }
```

ApplicationUser model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser()
        {
            Clients = new Collection<Client>();
        }

        [Index, MaxLength(60)]
        public override string UserName { get; set; }

        public Guid? EmpresaPaiID { get; set; }
        public Guid? EnderecoID { get; set; }
        public Guid? ServicoID { get; set; }
        public bool Ativo { get; set; }
        public bool CadastroCompleto { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual Endereco Endereco { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Vehicles", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "ServicesPerformed", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual ICollection<Servico> ServicosVans { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Available", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public bool Disponivel { get; set; }        

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "CompanyName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string NomeDaEmpresa { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "UserType", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public TipoUsuario TipoUsuario { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "CelPhone", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public override string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Phone", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "RG", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string RG { get; set; }

        [Cpf]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "CPF", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [Cnpj]
        [Display(Name = "CNPJ", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string CNPJEmpresa { get; set; } //Caso for empresa o tipo de usuário

        //[Cnpj]
        //[Display(Name = "RentalCNPJ", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        //public string CNPJLocadora { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Gender", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public string Sexo { get; set; }        

        public double Latitude { get; set; }

        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "PassangerSecurity", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public bool SeguroPassageiro { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "RemuneratedActivity", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public bool AtividadeRemunerada { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "DriverLicense", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public long CNH { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "Photo", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public HttpPostedFileBase Foto { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "DocumentOfTheCarRentalAgency", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public HttpPostedFileBase DocumentoLocadoraVeiculos { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "CertificateOfCriminalRecord", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public HttpPostedFileBase AtestadoAntecedentesCriminais { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "TicketDPVAT", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public HttpPostedFileBase BilheteDPVAT { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [Display(Name = "VehicleLicensingRegistration", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public HttpPostedFileBase RegistroLicenciamentoVeiculo { get; set; }

        public string FotoPath { get; set; }
        public string DocumentoLocadoraVeiculosPath { get; set; }
        public string AtestadoAntecedentesCriminaisPath { get; set; }
        public string BilheteDPVATPath { get; set; }
        public string RegistroLicenciamentoVeiculoPath { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
```

Na `view`, eu noto que o `Motorista` não é carregado por esta query. Isto gera um erro de referência nula, obviamente. Teria algo a ver com o `Lazy Loading`?

Como resolver?

Se precisar colo aqui o diagrama do banco de dados.

Comment: `Veiculo` está declarado dentro do mesmo contexto que `ApplicationUser`? `Empresa` também é um `ApplicationUser`?

Answer (score 1):

Como podemos ver, a classe Veiculo possui duas FK para ApplicationUser. São elas Empresa e Motorista.

```
public class Veiculo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid VeiculoID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid MotoristaID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid EmpresaID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Empresa { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Motorista { get; set; }
}
```

O EF não pode ter uma única coleção para duas FK. Como na classe abaixo:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
}
```

É necessário possuir duas coleções (VeiculosEmpresa e VeiculosMotorista), para que cada uma represente a parte reversa da relação Veiculo -> ApplicationUser.
Se for necessário uma coleção que traga todos os veículos, pode ser feito através de outra propriedade (Veiculos).

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> VeiculosEmpresa { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Veiculo> VeiculosMotorista { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Veiculo> Veiculos
    {
        get { return VeiculosEmpresa.Concat(VeiculosMotorista); }
    }
}
```

Para que isso funcione, é necessário incluir um mapeamento fluent no método OnModelCreating. Dessa forma, estamos informando ao Model Builder qual propriedade é refletida por qual coleção, e sua respectiva FK.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasRequired(m => m.Empresa).WithMany(m => m.VeiculosEmpresa).HasForeignKey(p => p.EmpresaID);
     modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasRequired(m => m.Motorista).WithMany(m => m.VeiculosMotorista).HasForeignKey(p => p.MotoristaID);
}
```

Comment: ótima ajuda, porém continuo não entendo como configurar, VeiculoEmpresa e VeiculoMotorista não existem, vc pode deixar pronto? Todo veículo tem no mínimo um motorista e no máximo um. A outra entidades que é o próprio motorista é do tipo ApplicationUser, ela pode ter 0 ou muitos veículos.

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasOptional(x => x.Motorista).WithMany(x => x.Veiculos);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Veiculo>().HasOptional(x => x.Empresa).WithMany(x => x.Veiculos);

com isso, no add-migration deu o seguinte erro:

Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Core.Models.Veiculo_Motorista' was not loaded because the type 'Core.Models.ApplicationUser' is not available.

Comment: Na verdade deveria ter uma foreign para uma coleção de acordo com o que eu disse em cima certo? Não entendo muito a sua solução, vai ter que mastigar mais! hehe vou rodar a migration inicial de novo

Comment: Deu erro de novo, tem algo errado no código que vc passou, é simples (era para ser).

Um ApplicationUser (classe esta na pergunta) pode ter muitos Veículos.
Cada veículo deve ter 1 ApplicationUser (Motorista), e um ApplicationUser (empresa), até então não vem ao caso, mas já pudemos arrumar também.

Comment: Veiculos na classe ApplicationUser representa os veiculos (a parte N ou muitos, como preferir).

Comment: Não tinha visto tuas FKs com atributo Required. Por isso o erro para gerar o migration, estavam sendo setadas com HasOptional. Sempre exiba somente a parte do código que interessa, o que não for relevante não precisa. Os códigos na nova resposta são idênticos aos anteriores, exceto pelo HasRequired que antes era HasOptional. Espero que tenhas entendido agora que uma coleção não pode referenciar duas FKs, eu sei que tu queres dizer 1<->N, porém o EF não funciona assim.